# How can I track a string value from local storage in google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, local-storage

I want to track the string value which is "generated" by this function in google analytics:

```
<script>
  var savedVal = localStorage.getItem("selectedoption");
  document.write(savedVal);
</script>
```

the savedVal is a string expression which comes from a dropdown on a different page.And I want to track this value.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Track it _as what_ …?

Comment: as a string in google analytics...the document.write (savedVal ) shows a value from a different page (on this page ; dropdown select)

Comment: What does your 'selectedOption' data look like?

Comment: <select class="form-control" id="mySelect" > 
 <option value=" Ihr anteil">Actimonda</option>...                                     
  <option value=" Ihr anteil">AOK Baden-Württemberg</option>                     ...it's a dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

### **Events**

That's the easiest and what it is actually designed for:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Your code could look like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Dropdown', savedVal);
```

Then you can get the information in the **Behaviour -> Events** report.

### **Custom Dimensions**

Another way to capture string data is to use custom dimensions. These are more powerful (eg you can associate those values with users or E-commerce products), but you have to pre-define them in the Google Analytics settings, and you're limited to 20 of them, so I would recommend you wait until you're more familiar with GA before using those:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

### **Content Groups**

There are similar to custom dimensions but are designed to categorize your content (pages), so don't think it applies to your case, but FYI:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en&ref_topic=1727167

Comment: thank you....so my code looks like this:https://jsfiddle.net/x26z832v/    ?

Comment: You can't call `ga()` with `savedVal` on line 12 before you've initialized `savedVal` on line 21

Comment: ok, I changed that like this https://jsfiddle.net/x26z832v/1/      ----but it doesn't work---I can't see the savedVal in ga. Any idesa ?

Comment: You should use that extension to check if the events are being sent to GA: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en, if not it's a problem with your code (you should look at your browser console and add some `console.log` calls to debug)